# Format not working in SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: sql-server, format

I have it on the good authority of Google searches that `FORMAT` became functional in SQL Server in 2012. I am connecting to a SQL Server 2014 Express connection, and `Format` throws an error:

> 'format' is not a recognized built-in function name.]

which is strange. The word `FORMAT` highlights in red, as the system recognizes the reserved word. It makes me worry that this version of SQL Server is somehow corrupt or in a diminished capacity.

Has anyone else ever encountered and overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out against which version of SQL Server you are really running your query, you may try:

```
SELECT @@VERSION AS 'SQL Server Version';
```

If this show something earlier than 2012, then it would explain your observations.  If you are executing against 2012+, then perhaps your syntax is very off, leading to this error message.